# Do I really need the Google Maps API key?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am planning to release a commercial website (I have ads there and a shop) which is freely available for everybody. I want to add a google map to show some points of interest. The question is: Do I need the google api key for that or can I just use the iframe code that google gives me? Theoretically that would work, too.

I searched google, but could not find a clear answer...

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

v2 of the Google Maps API is deprecated, so you should ideally use v3.

v3 does not need an API key as mentioned in the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#Welcome).

Since v3 is the official version now, I assume the links given in google maps are for the version. You can always just [try](http://jsfiddle.net/WmCTD/) and see if embedding the iframe works for you. Though as noted, you can't really customize the map, so you should use the API. It's very simple to set up a basic map (read the tutorial).

Comment: In the year 2012 they no longer say anything about API key on the linked page, but I found http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps-faq.html where they say: "For customers who need enhanced features such as advanced geocoding, added support, and full control over advertising, we offer Google Maps API for Business." and "If you're using the Maps API internally or for asset tracking purposes, you must have a Premier license. Additionally, if you are charging a fee for access to your Maps solution, [..], you are required to purchase the Maps API Premier."

Answer (score 2):

You **don't need the Google Maps API key** as long as you don't plan to include any special or customized maps in your website.

Using the `iframe` version is fine for basic Maps integration.

Comment: Customized in what way? Different icons or removed google links?

Comment: I don't know exactly, it's been a while since I've used it. But as you may have noticed, the iframe version doesn't allow you to include certain features. For everything else you would use the API version.

Answer (score 2):

The API Key is free anyway, so there is no problem in obtaining one. You should also be free to use the iframe as well, as long as your site is publicly available to everyone without a payed login or anything like that.

As long as you meet Google Maps TOS, you can use both. If you don't meet those TOS, don't use any of it.

Answer (score 1):

A Google Maps API key is required for v2 of the API, not for v3 as far as I know,
and neither for [requests to Static Maps API v2](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2010/02/static-map-markers-just-way-you-like-em.html).

Comment: And V3 supports the iframe stuff, which V2 did not?

Comment: Which exactly do you mean when referring to "iframe stuff" ?

Comment: The iframe link I can obtain when I click the "Link" link on google maps. There are 2 options, one is a plain link, the other one is html for embedding it into ur website - thats what I call "iframe stuff"